# Display result in a read-only <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display the result from the name field in a read-only text field called output. I have it working via `.innerHTML`, but I'm not sure how to get the result into a text box.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">
  <h1 style="color:green;">

  </h1>
  <h2>Text value property</h2>
  <p>
    Change the text of the text field, and then click the button below.
  </p>

  Name:<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  Output:<input type="text" id="myText" readonly>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to get the result inside a read-only text field.

Comment: Sorry, but your question has nothing to do with Java. It is JavaScript. Both languages look a bit similar regarding the syntax, but are completely different. You should remove the Java tag and add a JavaScript tag to get correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the readonly property on the input element that's going to hold the output :

```html
  <body>
    <h2>Text value property</h2>
    <p>Change the text of the text field, and then click the button below.</p>

    Name:<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey" />
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <input type="text" readonly id="output" style="display: none;">
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myText').value;
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.style.display = 'block';
        output.value = x;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using this code.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x;
}
</script>

<h2>Text value property</h2>
<p>
 Change the text of the text field, 
 and then click the button below. 
</p>

Name:<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
<button onClick="myFunction()">Try it</button><br>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the `.value` property of the output text input. The `.value` property can be written to via JavaScript even if it is read only to the user. Also, make sure that your input and output fields don't share the same ID:

```js
const myText = document.getElementById("myText");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById('tryit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  output.value = myText.value;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">
  <h2>Text value property</h2>
  <p>
    Change the text of the text field, and then click the button below.
  </p>

  Name:<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
  <button type="button" id="tryit">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  Output:<input type="text" id="output" readonly>
</body>

</html>
```

It's also a good practice to use `.addEventListener()` instead of `onclick` handlers. It is the newer way of doing event handlers.